# Is there a better way to say "at the midpoint of your life"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

"In the middle of the life" is too vague and doesn't mean the same thing, correct me if I am wrong, and "at the midpoint of your life" (after 20 years if you are going to live until 40) doesn't sound very idiomatic, so how would you say it?

For example:

> ____, a counter appears telling you how much time you have left to live in this strange fictional world.

Comment: @SamBC’s answer seems pretty good to me.  BUT, if you have a good reason to talk about such things, do you really want to miss the chance to inject into your work, even just a tiny allusion to the great Dante Alighieri? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Halfway through (your life)

That's probably the most general sort of phrase for it that I would use, though there are many different options available.

Comment: It does sound much better and natural.